# Validation accuracy when training and testing within same loop

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

Since I am training and testing within same loop (for each epoch on `training set`, network is applied on entire `validation set`).

Now does it make sense that the highest validation accuracy I get at some instant (nth epoch) be my network's highest accuracy or should I only use the validation accuracy once the graph has settled and weights don't change?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing `testing` with `validation`. If possible you should keep a separate test set of your dataset for testing only AFTER the training and validation are done.

Although you can use that test set for your validation, it's the best practice to do inference on a separate set of data that the model has never seen before.

**So answering your question**, if you get a spike in your validation accuracy then it can or cannot be the highest as more the number of epochs more the chances of greater accuracy (assuming the model is not overfitting the dataset).

In this situation, it's best that you save the model after every validation accuracy spike so you the best model with the highest validation accuracy after the training and validation has completed.